# How do you track if an activity is re-called from backstack?

Tags: android, animation

So I am trying to implement animations. 
Please assume that all the animations here is working as I have checked them one by one.

When an activity is new :
Enter : Slide in From Right
Exit : Slide out to Left

What I want to do now is, when user presses the back button the current activity will `Slide Out to Right` and the activity that is called from backstack will `Slide In From Left`

I've overridden the `onBackPressed` method and here is the code :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);
}
```

I tried the onRestart method in the AppCompatActivity and `overridePendingTransitions` but it is not working.

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_left, 0);
}
```

The animation of the activity called from backstack is still `Slide In From Right` which should be `Slide In From Left`. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is [onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart()) since it is always called no matter what.

OnResume() might not be called at all or possibly it is called to early in the process.

Please check my friend's [session](http://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack) for additional information.

Comment: The sessin is confusing. onStart is called everytime, which means it overrides the animation every time an activity is created. I want it to be overriden only when it is called from backstack.